# AJAX JSON "string" returns null in Javascript/Console

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, string, parsing

I have a very large dataset (30,000+ rows) as JSON getting returned via an Ajax call in my script.

However, when the data returns, just one property of the returned objects is wrong.

A property called `date` is returning `null` in the Javascript/Console log, but if you go to the Chrome response returned from the Ajax call, the `date` is a `string` as intended.

Any reasons why this string would be parsing to null in the response?

My code:

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (json) {
    console.log('This is literally the first line:', json);
    ...
  },
  ...
});
```

This is what the data "should" look like (this screenshot is from the "Network" tab of Chrome, it is the "Preview" of the request):
[image: What the data looks like]

And yet this is what Javascript returns in Console/scripting:
[image: What Javascript returns]

Any help would be amazing.

Cheers.

Comment: what  is the exact value of the `json` object in the success handler? Is it a string or object?

Comment: It should be a JSON object -- that is what is being returned by the API -- as seen in first screenshot. Seems to parse into an object fine in second screenshot, except with the `date` for some reason :(